"Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope'" when importing {authenticate} from "app/shopify.server" (Shopify App Extension in React)
I'm building a Shopify App Extension using this sample app as a template:
The sample app works as intended. I added an extension using yarn shopify app generate extension which also works. But from my my-app/extensions/post-purchase-ui/src/index.jsx file I always get the following error when trying to import { authenticate } from "app/shopify.server";.
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'https://shopify-tunnel-url.com/extensions/bf7aec3f-ae17-4835-99ad-d642c096198c/assets/post-purchase-ui.js' failed to load
 at dt (https://extensions.shopifycdn.com/shopifycloud/checkout-web/assets/ExtensionSandboxPostPurchase.latest.de.e953c1f6c2f63e67b5fd.worker.js:2:260114)
    at MessagePort.h (https://extensions.shopifycdn.com/shopifycloud/checkout-web/assets/ExtensionSandboxPostPurchase.latest.de.e953c1f6c2f63e67b5fd.worker.js:2:237691)

The exact same import works in the sample code from the app (my-app/app/routes/app.jsx) but not in my extension. How do I fix this?
